# Where will the charge be stored in this capacitor?

Tags: capacitance

A  capacitor whose charged plate is hemispherical,concave side is facing each other then will the charge be stored on concave surface like all other capacitors(i.e. parallel plate,cylindrical etc.) or will the charge be stored on outer,convex surface like charged sphere or shell?

Comment: Inside with a non-uniform charge distribution with most at and around the edges.

Comment: @ Farcher may you mention the reason for this ?

Comment: The positive and negative charges will be as close to one another as possible.  With a charged sphere all the charges are of the same sign and want to get as far from one another as possible besides there would be no way they could distribute themselves so that the electric field inside the conducting sphere was zero.